# Terminal is unable to execute anything

Tags: mysql, macos

first time posting here.  Hopefully you guys can help with this issue I'm having.

I've been trying to install MySQL on My macbook (OS X Sierra) using Macports. Unfortunately whenever I try to run any command (mysql_install_db, mysql_secure_installation) I just get a simple `command not found` response. I've edited my environment variable using `.bash_profile` and it seems to be correct to me:

`/opt/local/bin/lib/mysql56/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

I've tried cd'ing right into the directory where the commands are located and just running `sudo mysql_install_db` and I've also tried running `sudo -u _mysql mysql_install_db` all to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You get this error for all commands,or just `mysql` commands?

Comment: Did you logout and login again after editing `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.